# Why the command button is not being displayed in my emulator?

Tags: java-me, midp

I have already added 5 cammands in a form and I want to add a sixth but It does not display the sixth?

I am posting my codes below.

```
public Command getOk_Lastjourney() {
        if (Ok_Lastjourney == null) {
            // write pre-init user code here
            Ok_Lastjourney = new Command("Last Journey", Command.OK, 0);
            // write post-init user code here
        }
        return Ok_Lastjourney;
    }


public Form getFrm_planjourney() {
        if (frm_planjourney == null) {                                 
            // write pre-init user code here
            frm_planjourney = new Form("Plan journey", new Item[] { getTxt_From(), getTxt_To(), getCg_usertype(), getCg_userpref(), getCg_searchalgo() });                                    
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getExt_planjourney());
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getOk_planjourney());
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getOk_planFare());
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getOk_planDistance());
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getOk_planTime());
            frm_planjourney.addCommand(getOk_planRoute());
            frm_planjourney.setCommandListener(this);                                  
            // write post-init user code here
            System.out.println("Appending.....");

            System.out.println("Append completed...");
            System.out.println(frm_planjourney.size());
            frm_planjourney.setItemStateListener(this);
        }                         
        return frm_planjourney;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Given `System.out.println` I assume you were debugging with emulator, right? in that case it would be really helpful to provide a screen shot showing how exactly *does not display the sixth* looks like.

Most likely you just got too many commands to fit to area allocated so that some of them are not shown until scrolled. There is also a chance that *sixth* command was reassigned to some other soft-button and you didn't notice that. Or there's something else - hard to tell with details you provided.

A general note - handling six actions with commands might be not the best choice in MIDP UI. For stuff like that, consider using [lcdui List API](http://download.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html) instead. `IMPLICIT` kind of lists allow for more reliable and user friendly design than commands.